# How do I "throw" a tokio_postgres::Error?

Tags: rust, tokio-postgres

I want to create a validation when I'm creating a new user. Already an email error must be returned. Like this:

```
pub async fn insert_usuario(usuario: &Usuario) -> Result<&Usuario, Error> {
    let mut fetch_usuario= Usuario { nome: String::new(), email: String::new(), senha: String::new()};
    
    match get_usuario_by_email(&usuario.email).await {
        Ok(u) =>{fetch_usuario=u},
        Err(e) =>{println!("Erro {}",e)}
    }

    if !fetch_usuario.email.eq(""){
        println!("Email {} already exists.", fetch_usuario.email);
        return tokio_postgres::Error("User already exists")
    }

    let client = get_client().await;
    client.execute("insert into usuario (nome, email, senha) values ($1, $2, $3);", 
        &[&usuario.nome, &usuario.email, &usuario.senha])
        .await?;
    Ok(usuario)
}
```

But compiling shows:

```
error[E0423]: cannot initialize a tuple struct which contains private fields
   --> src/lib.rs:95:16
    |
95  |         return tokio_postgres::Error("User already exists")
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: constructor is not visible here due to private fields
   --> /Users/msansone/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-postgres-0.7.5/src/error/mod.rs:366:18
    |
366 | pub struct Error(Box<ErrorInner>);
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ private field
help: consider importing one of these items instead
    |
```

How can I generate a new/custom `tokio_postgres::Error`?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, but rather copy-paste the text.

Comment: You cannot create a `tokio_postgres::error::Error` yourself. You might want to define a new error type instead.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/latest/tokio_postgres/error/struct.Error.html) doesn't show any way to create an error, so it's likely not intended to be generated outside of the library.

That makes sense, however. "User already exists" is not a *database* error, like the server being down, - it's the *logical* error, and you probably shouldn't treat them the same way anyway. It's expected that you create your own error type, probably using either [`thiserror`](https://lib.rs/thiserror) (for structured errors) or [`anyhow`](https://lib.rs/anyhow) (for opaque ones).